# Converting an array into a hash with format { value => position_in_array }

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have an array of numbers in string format, and I want to convert them into a hash where the keys are the numbers and the values are the positions of those numbers in the array. So for example:

```
["1", "5", "3"]
```

should result in:

```
{ 1 => 0, 5 => 1, 3 => 2 }
```

I have the following code, which works:

```
my_hash = {}
my_array.each do |number_string|
  my_hash[number_string.to_i] = my_array.index(number_string)
end
```

which iterates through the array and pushes each value and its position into the hash.

Is there a shorter and more elegant way to do it? Maybe something similar to Ruby's `to_a` function, but more like `to_h(options)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Hash[["1", "5", "3"]
.map.with_index{|e, i| [e.to_i, i]}]
# => {1=>0, 5=>1, 3=>2}
```

or

```
["1", "5", "3"]
.each_with_object({}).with_index{|(e, h), i| h[e.to_i] = i}
# => {1=>0, 5=>1, 3=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["1", "5", "3"]
ha = Hash[arr.map.with_index {|a, i| [a.to_i, i]}]
puts "ha: #{ha.inspect}" 

irb(main):038:0> arr=["1", "5", "3"]
=> ["1", "5", "3"]
irb(main):039:0> Hash[arr.map.with_index {|a, i| [a, i]}]
=> {"1"=>0, "5"=>1, "3"=>2}
irb(main):040:0> Hash[arr.map.with_index {|a, i| [a.to_i, i]}]
=> {1=>0, 5=>1, 3=>2}
```